# sympy.geometry Point class is working slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I have a code which reads unstructured mesh. I wrote wrappers around geometric entities of `sympy.geometry` such as:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, parent_mesh):
        self.shape = sympy.geometry.Point(x,y)
        self.parent_mesh = parent_mesh
        self.parent_cell = list()
```

Everything works fine but initialization of `sympy.geometry.Point` takes a lot of time for each `Point`. Actually, the code did not finish execution for thousands of points. Similar code written in C++ finished in a few seconds. Without it the code is fast enough (I removed it and timed). I read that a possible reason could be that `sympy.geometry` converts floating point numbers to rationals for precision. Is there a way (flag) to speed up `sympy.geometry` as I do not need exact precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Point` class documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/points.html#module-sympy.geometry.point), specifically, in one of the first examples:

> Floats are automatically converted to Rational unless the evaluate flag is `False`.

So, you could pass a flag named `evaluate` during initialization of your `Point` classes:

```
self.shape = sympy.geometry.Point(x,y, evaluate=False)
```

which apparently signals what you're after.

Comment: Yes this solved the problem. I should have read the documentation better. Thanks.

Comment: Although now sympy.geometry.Triangle is working very slow and there is nothing about `evaluate` in this case.

Comment: `Triangle` can be initialized with 3 `Point`s so the best you could do is make those Points not convert to Rationals.

Comment: I did but no improvement. Also as the number of digits of points increase execution time increases dramatically.